# How to use case when in sql query

Tags: sql

```
query="SELECT a.id, b.id
        FROM tab_a a, tab_b b
        WHERE a.ref = b.ref
        AND a.amount = -b.amount
        AND NOT a.tot AND NOT b.tot
        AND a.a_id = %(a_id)s AND b.a_id = %(a_id)s
        {p_id_condition}
        ORDER BY a.date desc"
```

i am trying

first try to match the ref, but if no pair found, try to match the amount

Comment: What? What is this query doing, which RDBMS ?

Comment: How about using an `OR` in the `WHERE`-clause?

Comment: Does your query execute without error? How do you want to use `case`, or do you mean something else entirely? Please elucidate.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    b.id
FROM tab_a a
INNER JOIN tab_b b
    ON a.ref = b.ref OR
       a.amount = -b.amount
WHERE
    NOT a.tot AND
    NOT b.tot AND
    a.a_id = %(a_id)s AND
    b.a_id = %(a_id)s
    {p_id_condition}
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

I rewrote your query using explicit join syntax, which isolated and revealed the two join conditions you mentioned in your question.  Then I changed the and to an or, which would seem to be what you want.

Comment: @sagi Changed the join condition to an `OR` between the two criteria, and refactored to use an explicit join.

Comment: Oh I missed that :D, though I'm not sure that's what he needs . Bad question.

Comment: And bad answer, but don't downvote me, downvote the question!  Oh what the hell, downvote me too!

Comment: Nah, only wrong / misleading answers should be downvoted in my opinion . Your answers are never one of them .